# RegEx doesn't work with .NET, but does with other RegEx implementations

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex

I'm trying to match strings that look like this:

```
http://www.google.com
```

But not if it occurs in larger context like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> http://www.google.com </a>
```

The regex I've got that does the job in a couple different RegEx engines I've tested (PHP, ActionScript) looks like this:

```
(?<!["'>]\b*)((https?://)([A-Za-z0-9_=%&@?./-]+))\b
```

You can see it working here:  http://regexr.com?36g0e

The problem is that that particular RegEx doesn't seem to work correctly under .NET.

```
private static readonly Regex fixHttp = new Regex(@"(?<![""'>]\b*)((https?://)([A-Za-z0-9_=%&@?./-]+))\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
private static readonly Regex fixWww = new Regex(@"(?<=[\s])\b((www\.)([A-Za-z0-9_=%&@?./-]+))\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

public static string FixUrls(this string s)
{
    s = fixHttp.Replace(s, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
    s = fixWww.Replace(s, "<a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a>");
    return s;
}
```

Specifically, .NET doesn't seem to be paying attention to the first `\b*`. In other words, it correctly fails to match this string:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

But it incorrectly matches this string (note the extra spaces):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> http://www.google.com </a>
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong or how to work around it?

Comment: There is no replace or match in your regexr link... And you shouldn't put quantifiers on word boundaries. In .NET (I'm thinking of C# here), you have to escape the double quotes with double quotes so that `"` becomes `""`.

Comment: @Jerry - Yeah, I'm doing all that in my actual C# code - edited.

Comment: I remember using some RE tools and they had an option to select the engine executing the RE. There was a .Net engine as it executed RE differently.

Comment: @SoMoS - Agreed, they clearly do. I tested it at http://www.myregextester.com/index.php, and it shows it working under PHP, but failing (as in my own testing) under .NET.

Comment: You could really improve the readability of your patterns if a) you used verbatim strings (getting rid of all the double backslashes), and b) only escaped what you have to: e.g. `@"(?<![""'>]\b)((https?://)([A-Za-z0-9_=%&@?./-]+))\b"`

Comment: I've found that they are called 'dialects'. I cannot find the page I mentioned before but was something like this one: http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: @SoMoS the term "flavors" is actually more common. @KenSmith: I don't see why your pattern should fail for the second input. The lookbehind wants a quote, apostrophe, or closing angle bracket. And in your second example the character before `http` is neither of those (it's a space). But your lookbehind is a negative one, so you *want* there to be something else than a quote, apostrophe or space. I'd say .NET is the one treating this situation correctly, and I think the others might do something weird due to the `\b*`.

Comment: Someone had an answer that got deleted which suggested I use a `\s*` rather than the `\b*`. That solved it for me - though I'm not sure why.

Comment: @KenSmith `\b` matches a position and not a character. If you want to assert that there is no `["'>]` left of `http`, but ignore whitespace in between, then `\s*` is the way to go. If that is what you intend, I can vote to undelete the answer (I believe it was deleted, because I pointed out that the reasoning behind the suggestion was incorrect)

Comment: @m.buettner - Yes, that's what I was intending: I wanted to assert that there was no `["'>]` (ignoring any whitespace) left of `http`. Thanks for everyone's help - and I'd be happy to give either of you two credit for the answer :-).

Comment: @KenSmith I think that what was truly intended was to have `(?<!["'>]\s*)\b` That's that and then you can unescape some of the characters in the character class as pointed out by m.buettner in an earlier comment.

Comment: I went ahead and made the code changes that were mentioned above (use verbatim strings and remove unneeded escapes) while I was tweaking the formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was waiting for one of the folks who actually originally answered this question to pop the answer down here, but since they haven't, I'll throw it in.

I'm not *precisely* sure what was going wrong, but it turns out that in .NET, I needed to replace the `\b*` with a `\s*`. The `\s*` doesn't seem to work with other RegEx engines (I only did a little bit of testing), but it does work correctly with .NET. The documentation I've read around `\b` would lead me to believe that it should match whitespace leading up to a word as well, but perhaps I've misunderstood, or perhaps there are some weirdnesses around captures that different engines handle differently.

At any rate, this is my final RegEx:

```
(?<!["'>]\s*)((https?:\/\/)([A-Za-z0-9_=%&@\?\.\/\-]+))\b
```

I don't understand what was going wrong well enough to give any real context for why this change works, and I dislike RegExes enough that I can't quite justify the time figuring it out, but maybe it'll help someone else eventually :-).